# Passenger dies on UnknownHttpMethod exception

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

**Update** I tried catching this exception in my application controller, but to no avail. I've also updated Passenger to 3.0.7 and submitted an issue to their tracker.

---

I have a Rails 3.0.4 application running on FreeBSD 8.2 with Apache 2.2.17, Passenger 3.0.2 and Ruby 1.9.2-p180 that's been dying every other day. Here's the backtrace from the error log:

```
    [ pid=85853 thr=17189069660 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-05-04 12:08:13.022 ]: 
*** Exception ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod in application
(U<F9>i<CA>,fs<C8>6<F6><C0>b<F2><C5>hVj<BE><D9>#<F5><80><99><EA>=n, 
accepted HTTP methods are OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT, 
PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK, VERSION-CONTROL, REPORT, CHECKOUT,
CHECKIN, UNCHECKOUT, MKWORKSPACE, UPDATE, LABEL, MERGE, BASELINE-CONTROL, MKACTIVITY,
ORDERPATCH, ACL, SEARCH, and PATCH) (process 85853, thread #<Thread:0x0000080118c6b8>):
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:76:in `request_method'
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `before_dispatch'
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:12:in `call'
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
            from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
            from /usr/local/docs/arc/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
            from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
            from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.2/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
    [Wed May 04 12:08:13 2011] [notice] child pid 1567 exit signal Bus error (10)
    [Wed May 04 12:08:16 2011] [notice] child pid 1195 exit signal Bus error (10)
    [Wed May 04 12:08:20 2011] [notice] child pid 1600 exit signal Bus error (10)
    [Wed May 04 12:08:20 2011] [notice] child pid 1590 exit signal Bus error (10)
    [Wed May 04 12:08:21 2011] [notice] child pid 1199 exit signal Bus error (10)
    [Wed May 04 12:08:21 2011] [notice] child pid 726 exit signal Bus error (10)...etc...
```

Once this happens, the application goes down. Apache still serves up static files in the public directory, but no application. Of course the gobbledygook where the http verb should be concerns me (and makes it impossible to track down via google), but will rescuing this exception in the application_controller actually prevent passenger from dying? Anyone seen this before?

Comment: bonus points for catchy headline

Comment: Thanks, always thought I should have been a turn-of-the-century newspaper man! =)

Comment: While I'm waiting for the one other person on the internet that's had this happen to them, here's my initial solution: calling rescue_from ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod, then logging the error and returning a 400 status. I'll post another comment when, or if this happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, it looks like your application server (fastcgi or apache moduel?) is dieing quite ungracefully when an illegal HTTP verb is received.

I fully expect that you can filter this in the apache config for the site (be it /etc/apache2/site-available/... or .htaccess in your virtual folder (mod_access)

However, I think it is sane to just report the trace to the Passenger devs as a bug. The info is right there in the trace

```
 U<F9>i<CA>,fs<C8>6<F6><C0>b<F2><C5>hVj<BE><D9>#<F5><80><99><EA>=n
```

is not a valid verb. It could be trivial to reproduce using netcat on port 80 of your webserver (remember the Host header)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've submitted an issue to their googlecode tracker. I fully agree, though. Something like this should never get to the app itself.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this. I haven't heard anything from the passenger guys, so I'm looking into how to get apache to deal with this.